# @ApplicationException with Java 1.7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, migration

I have web service with method that throw my custom exeption.

```
@WebMethod void someMethod(...) throws MyException
```

`MyException` class is annotated with `@ApplicationException`

```
@ApplicationException  
class public MyException extends Exception {...}
```

I was build my project using `maven`, `JDK 1.6` and `jaxws-maven-plugin` for generating WSDL, and all worked well.
But now I want do the same with `JDK 1.7`, and now I get error

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at private java.lang.Throwable[] com.MyPackage.MyExceptionBean.suppressed
        at com.MyPackage.MyExceptionBean
```

Any ideas?

Different is that with JDK 1.6 class MyExceptionBean was generated like

```
public class MyExceptionBean {

    private String message;
```

but with JDK 1.7

```
public class MyExceptionBean {

    private String message;
    private Throwable[] suppressed;
```

jaxws-maven-plugin

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.10</version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is issue of `jaxws-maven-plugin` and `java 7` :-(
[issue tracker](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS_COMMONS-72)

with version 2.2 works well

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
```